# Failed autodiscover in chrome

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I wrote website with using fullcalendar. I get events from my exchnage server. If open site in Edge browser, all ok. But if use chrome, i got error when use autodiscover: failed: WebException (The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.)

I enable kerberos like this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2012/11/05/ews-from-a-web-application-using-windows-authentication-and-impersonation/

```
        TraceListener trs = new TraceListener();
        service.TraceListener = trs;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.Timeout = 700;
        string email = GetEmail();
        WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
        impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate();
        service.Credentials = new 
        WebCredentials(CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(email, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);//got error
        impersonationContext.Undo();
```

How open my site in chrome without error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. Use http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates, then added my web and exchange server to "Kerberos Delegation Server Whitelist" and "Authentication Server Whitelist"